# Absolute continuity with respect to the product measure

Tags: measure-theory, product-space, total-variation

Let $\mu$ be a measure over the product space $X\times Y$, $X$ is any topological space and $Y$ is either Lindelöf or compact, and let $\mu_y$ and $\mu_x$ denote the marginals of $\mu$ on $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Suppose that there is a regular conditional distribution $\mu(\cdot|y)$ such that 
$$ d\mu(x,y)=d\mu(x|y)\times d\mu_y(y). $$

If $\mu(\cdot|y)$ is continuous in the total variation norm with respect to $y$, is it true that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the product measure in $X\times Y$?

Comment: Well...is it? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I would like it not to be true if I’m honest but I can’t find an example. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure actually. Cannot find a counterexample either.